# Microsoft SQL Server: update multiple rows using combined values and compare them to values from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables im my SQL Server database.

Table 1 looks like this:

```
Material   Semifinished     Number
-----------------------------------
Steel      Flat 1x2
Iron       Round 100x200
```

Table 2 looks like this:

```
Material   Semifinished     Number
-----------------------------------
Steel      Flat 1x2         8991
Iron       Round 100x200    1234
```

Now I want to insert the values of the column `Number` from Table 2 into the Column `Number` from Table 1. The criteria for that should be the combination of column `Material` and column `Semifinished`

I tried this before:

```
update T1
set T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
from TABLE1 AS T1 
inner join TABLE2 AS T2 on T1.MATERIAL + T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.MATERIAL + T2.SEMIFINISHED
where T1.MATERIAL + T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.MATERIAL + T2.SEMIFINISHED
```

I also tried this one:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD [NEWCOL] varchar(100)
ALTER TABLE TABLE2 ADD [NEWCOL] varchar(100)

update TABLE1 
set NEWCOL = MATERIAL + SEMIFINISHED 

update TABLE2 
set NEWCOL = MATERIAL + SEMIFINISHED

update T1
set T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
from TABLE1 AS T1 
inner join TABLE2 AS T2 on T1.NEWCOL = T2.NEWCOL
where T1.NEWCOL = T2.NEWCOL
```

Comment: `inner join TABLE2 as T2 on T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL and T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.SEMIFINISHED`

Comment: Why did you use a WHERE clause with the same condition as the JOIN?   What are you thinking that will do?

Comment: And the problem is what?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not reproducible.

This works for me:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
  Material varchar(255)
, Semifinished varchar(255)
, Number int
);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
  Material varchar(255)
, Semifinished varchar(255)
, Number int
);

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES ('Steel','Flat 1x2',NULL),('Iron','Round 100x200',NULL);

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES ('Steel','Flat 1x2',8991),('Iron','Round 100x200',1234);

update T1
set T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
from @Table1 AS T1 
inner join @Table2 AS T2 on T1.MATERIAL + T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.MATERIAL + T2.SEMIFINISHED
where T1.MATERIAL + T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.MATERIAL + T2.SEMIFINISHED

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

Result:

```
Material    Semifinished    Number
Steel       Flat 1x2        8991
Iron        Round 100x200   1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help but I found the solution.

I changed the last part a little bit:

```
update TABLE1
set NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
from TABLE1 AS T1 
inner join TABLE2 AS T2 on T1.NEWCOL = T2.NEWCOL
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(
    Material NVARCHAR(200),
    Semifinished NVARCHAR(200),
    Number INT
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE(
    Material NVARCHAR(200),
    Semifinished NVARCHAR(200),
    Number INT
)

INSERT INTO @T1 SELECT 'Steel','Flat 1x2',NULL
INSERT INTO @T1 SELECT 'Iron','Round 100x200',NULL

INSERT INTO @T2 SELECT 'Steel','Flat 1x2',8991
INSERT INTO @T2 SELECT 'Iron','Round 100x200',1234

update T1
set T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
from @T1 AS T1 
inner join @T2 AS T2 on T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL AND
    T1.SEMIFINISHED = T2.SEMIFINISHED

SELECT * FROM @T1
SELECT * FROM @T2
```